# Baseboard radiator pipes running along edge of room

Tags: plumbing, baseboard, radiator, gap

My house has baseboard radiators (water, not steam if it matters) and one room has the piping enter at the southwest corner, run all the way along the west wall, then feed the heaters on the north wall. They used to be covered by a built-in cabinet unit, but I removed the cabinets.

How can I effectively seal the floor/wall gaps and/or cover the whole pipe run?

Here are the pipes at the southwest corner:
[image: Pipes emerging from the wall and running along the floor]

Comment: Can you access the basement ceiling because in my house all those pipes are in the ceiling.

Comment: @cybernard Sadly it's a split-level and this half of the house doesn't have an accessible area underneath. All the other rooms don't have this problem. I've also considered just having them moved to the south wall instead of the north wall, but that'd move them from an exterior to interior wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option one - buy some baseboard radiator cover (just the cover) and put it over them. In the grander version of this you might do some replumbing to get them up inside it more neatly, but if it's heating season now, I suggest waiting for summer.

Option two - build a small pipe chase around them. Basically a board in front of the pipes, and a board on top of the pipes. That may need a board behind the pipes for stability - screw that one to the wall, screw them all together. Provide an easily unscrewed access port over that valve. The top board and supporting boards should tolerate being stepped on by normal humans, or perhaps even heavy ones.

Comment: I was actually already thinking of option 2 on a larger scale so that I could put a bookshelf on top - figured I'd check for a second opinion. Thanks!

Comment: Do provide an access port / cover for that valve and any other things of that sort.

Comment: Yeah, both valves